# How to show different field value in a vf edit page

Tags: visualforce, community, salesforcedx, pagereference

Right now I have a vf page that shows like this:

```
<div class="col-md-5">
  <input id="contactFirstName" type="text"  class="form-control" name="userFirstName" maxlength=40 value="{!contact.firstName1}" />
</div>
```

But now I want show another field firstName2 if that filed is not blank instead of firstName1, but if firstName2 is blank I still wanna show firstName1.

So how should I do this?

Like {!contact.firstName2}?{!contact.firstName2}:{!contact.firstName1}

Any help will be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code should work. just replace the firstName & lastname field with appropriate fields

```
<apex:page standardController="contact">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <input id="contactFirstName" type="text"  class="form-control" name="userFirstName" maxlength="40" value="{! IF(contact.firstName != '' , contact.firstName , contact.lastname)}" />
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works fine